# How to replace HTML special character in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var Value="!@#$'&\";
 if (value.indexOf("'") > 0) {
        value = value.replace(/'/g, "&apos;"); 

    }
```

All Text is replaced except last character "\".
How do i replace it with same.

Comment: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal. Please add proper code.

Comment: Actually all characters are passed through except \. When i enter \ ,it throws error

Answer (score 1):

This is the currently 'accepted' code to convert *all* (or a range of them) possible unicode characters to their equivalent HTML entity:

```
var value = "!@#$'&\\";
value = value.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
  return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have new information about this solution from @MarcoS:

```
var value = "!@#$'&\\";
value = value.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
  return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
});
```

I am not sure when it started, but as of today 2019/07/10, this code will not work in chrome, but it does work in firefox/safari. It will cause the lowercase 's' character to trip the regex and output as encoded `&#115;` A coworker of mine found that this character `\u017f`, now in the unicode standard, and causes this code to act strangely:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17f/index.htm

If you instead use the following, it should work in all browsers:

```
var value = "!@#$'&\\";
value = value.replace(/[\u00A0-\u017e\u0180-\u9999]/gim, function(i) {
  return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated range. I have been bashing my head against a wall about why my `s` characters were getting encoded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error, that once fixed will also replace the `\` character:
You need an extra backslash because backslash is a special character and needs to be escaped.

```
var value= "!@#$'&\\";
```